# Связать программу с сервером (для авторизации)

Tags: delphi

Мне надо, что бы моя программа могла подключаться к серверу с Б/Д (как на любом сайте): вводите логин, вводите пароль и входите в систему. Нужно это для большой программы с базами данных, чтобы открывалась персональная Б/Д, созданная именно этим пользователем. Так же хотел бы узнать, как сделать при авторизации рядом кнопочку для смены пароля и регистрации.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте компоненты ADO для работы с базой данных, в TADOConnection есть свойство LoginPromt, по умолчанию установленное в true, оно будет выводить окошко логина для коннекта. Если хотите формировать строку подключения сами к разным базам, серверам, под разными логинами используйте свойство ConnectionString - формат строки курите тут http://www.codemaker.co.uk/it/tips/ado_conn.htm, в зависимости от используемой БД.